# Sql trigger to update column value in a given time period

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a table called Settings with columnA, columnB, columnC, columnD, columnE and their value as followed:

columnA = 1000 columnB = 100 columnC = 200 columnD = 18 columnE = 6

I want to change the value in columnA/B/C when the time is between 18pm to 6am.

I'm thinking of somekind of a trigger that updates the values by looking at the timestamp but I just don't know how to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: A trigger is only called when a qualifying statement is executed against the table. You probably want to build a SQL agent job instead and execute it at specific times

Comment: How many rows does the table have?

Comment: It only have 1 single row :) There are more columns then those 5 I've posted, but they are not relevant.

Comment: What exactly would you like to do? Update columns ABC to what value? At any time between 18pm and 6am or at the beginning of that interval? Or you simply want to schedule a job sometime at your wish as opposed to random time calculated by some script?

Comment: The columns value should be changed to columnA = 1, columnB = 50, columnC = 1 when the time has passed 18pm. Then I want to change values back to the old ones after 6am

Comment: You need to add a job or two and schedule them. [Here is MSDN article explaining how to do it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx#SSMSProcedure).

Comment: It sounds like this could just be implemented as computed columns or a view (depending on update requirements and/or data hiding requirements). The view definition/computed column could check the time and return a fixed value (or one of two underlying values stored in "hidden" columns)

Answer (score 0):

If you can control the application reading the table then could you create a view that checks the time and returns the values you require?

Something like:

```
SELECT 
  [COLUMN1],
  CASE 
    WHEN DATEPART("hh", GETDATE()) BETWEEN 6 AND 14 THEN 1
    ELSE [COLUMN2] END AS [COLUMN2],
  [COLUMN3]
FROM [TABLE1]
```

**Edit:**

If you're querying the table via SQL built within your app you can alter the SQL query to return these values with the `CASE` above:

```
CASE 
    WHEN DATEPART("hh", GETDATE()) BETWEEN 6 AND 14 THEN 1
    ELSE [COLUMN2] END AS [COLUMN2],
```

Comment: The application to read and write from the database is something I've created too.

Comment: You should be able to redirect the reads to the view and the writes back to the table, just depends on how everything is set-up. Having a view that always returns correct values removes a step that could fail (like the SQL agent).